# Stop OWA redirect over https iis

Tags: ssl, iis, https, windows-server-2016, exchange-2016

I'm currently running a Windows Server 2016 machine, partnered with Exchange Server 2016 and IIS 10. I'm trying to separate the Exchange owa page and run a web host separate from the same IIS web host such that https://mail.example.com redirects to https://mail.example.com/owa and https://example.com just uses the default root domain. I know this isn't best practice for security reasons however this is the way I have / want to do it.

However with just a normal Exchange and IIS setup all the latest versions to date. I've configured a SSL cert through Let's Encrypt Authority. However with the binding to the SSL certificate the root directory automatically redirects to OWA virtual directory when using https protocol for a secure connection.

Does anyone know how to stop that redirect unless typed as mail.domain.com. I know it's possible as when running server 2008 and exchange 2010 it worked as intended out of the box. I just want a fix as clients aren't seeing my page because of it.

Thanks so much in advance.

Edit: As per conversation in comments I've since tried to create a second site within IIS and bind the hostname to mail.domain.com, however when trying to do the same with https only one ssl cert can be used across all sites with https. So i've used one containing all domains.

However even though setup as such with different sites and hostnames directing to the other sites https://example.com still redirects to https://mail.example.com/owa for some reason.

Comment: Same problem may occur on a larger environment, too. It isn't necessary to make this off-topic by mentioning you try to set this up at home. You could go straight to the point.

Comment: Fair point. Didn't think of that. Just didn't want someone to suggest sperating the exchange and web server. Just want it to be clear. Should of just said that.

Comment: Exchange use IIS intensively, any IIS restart will block Exchange, having a normal webserver on it can bring you a load of problem

Comment: @yagmoth555, probably just stop `/` redirecting to `/owa`, but the question could have been stated more clearly.

Comment: @EsaJokinen I think he need to create its bind in IIS and dont use default web site of possible, but can be hard to achieve if both website use same domain name

Comment: Would it help to bind one to mail.domain.com and the other to domain.com then ?

Comment: yes, it would help, as it would separate each site in IIS :) if it work good let me know, will rewrite as an answer

Comment: Will work on it tomorrow and give an answer thanks

Comment: @yagmoth555 Now adjusted the post to explain attempted fix and tried to re-clarify issue for other / new users viewing post